# Turn off echo of getpass.getpass() in IDLE

Tags: python-3.x, python-idle

I would like to enter a password into the IDLE terminal in Windows without an echo.

Normally entering passwords is possible with python using the function getpass.getpass(), but in IDLE there comes up the following warning message:

```
GetPassWarning: Can not control echo on the terminal. 
Warning: Password input may be echoed.
```

I found out, this is because IDLE replaces the sys.stdin with a different object:

```
if sys.stdin is not sys.__stdin__:
    return fallback_getpass(prompt, stream)
```

However, I could not find a solution. Does anybody have an answer or another way to enter a password into the IDLE terminal without an echo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an IDLE maintainer with some familiarity with IDLE internals, I do not believe that it is possible to suppress character display but not otherwise change behavior in response to `input('prompt')` without major changes to IDLE code.

But even that would be insufficient for `getpass.getpass` since it calls one of `unix_getpass`, `win_getpass`, or `default_getpass`, and the first two use *system_specific* low-level functions that *bypass* stdin.

In terms of design intent: IDLE is, as its name says, a program development environment.  Developed programs normally, and sometimes must be, executed by Python directly, without going through IDLE.  Python normally runs attached to a terminal window.  IDLE's Shell is based on a tkinter Text widget, which is a multiline editor, not a terminal.  This is why one can enter, recall, and edit complete multiline statements rather than only a single line at a time.